# IPA app can't be installed on iPhone (Provisioning file)

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, provisioning-profile

I have a problem with an app that I'm developing in Ionic. We have an enterprise in the company and we use a provisioning file to get all the devices we use for development.

Locally, I use Xcode and I can test the app, but one of the devices can't install the app. I changed the provisioning file when I created the push services, before It works properly, but then I can't fix it.

When you try to install the app in the device, the installation stop and nobody knows how to fix it.

1. Why in Apple dev console a few of them have "Managed by xcode" and
   others no?
2. Why I have to set 2 provisioning files?

[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: Is it developer provisioning file or Ad-Hoc?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your second question -**"Why I have to set 2 provisioning files?"**
Under **'Build Settings'** there are two tabs **'Combined'** and **'Levels'**. You have to select **'Combined'** tab to set only 1 provisioning profile.